# Stripe event management

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

We're implementing Stripe and Paypal for payments on our website (both offered as alternatives on the same page).
For Stripe, we went with the *simple* implementation approach as per sample code here:

```
   <form action="/stripeAction" method="POST">
      <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh"
        data-amount="2000"
        data-name="Demo Site"
        data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
        data-image="/128x128.png">
      </script>
    </form>
```

This works perfectly, and stripe automatically disables its own "Buy now" button once payment is made (to avoid double click).

As the same HTML page also contains the Paypal express checkout link, what would be the best approach to have it disabled as well (to avoid someone clicking it, while page is just reloading from a successful Stripe payment)?

So far we tried the *onsubmit* event but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<form action="/stripeAction" method="POST" onsubmit="DO_SOME_ACTION">
```

Any idea/advice/hint would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 2):

What I'd recommend you do is create an event handler on the Checkout open event that disables the PayPal button:

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

The only downside to that is it assumes the payment method works in Checkout (i.e., that the card isn't declined). As a failsafe, you could re-enabled the PayPal button in the Checkout closed event handler if no Stripe token exists.

Hope that helps!
Larry

PS I work on Support at Stripe.